# Cannot select a record in Customers (CustTable)

Tags: axapta

Sometimes we are getting these messages:

> Cannot select a record in Customers (CustTable). Customer account: , . The SQL database has issued an error.

We are also getting them on `SalesTable`, `EmplTable`.

How to know more info about such errors and how to fix them.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe these errors happen when AX loses connectivity to SQL.  You most likely have network issues.

EDIT: To add to my answer, I get these **regularly** because our networking team has been having various issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may have syncing issues. You can sync your DB in "Admin - Periodic - SQL administration - Table Actions - Synchronize database".

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like an error that is caused out side of AX, and being bubbled up to the app.  Networking is an obvious place to start (as noted above by Alex), but also check teh integrity of the database.  DBCC CHECKDB should be run to see if the DB is 100%

[Link to CHECK DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx)

Also performance can cause time-outs causing these issues.  Good indexing can prevent these time outs.  Heres a link to AX indexing best practices, but indexing can be more complex.

[Link to AX Indexing best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa621872%28v=ax.10%29.aspx)

Also check resources on your AX SQL server, especially wrt database I/O.